# Java. Socket, InputStream, InputStreamReader. How can I find a value for the amount of data in the buffer

Tags: java, sockets, buffer, inputstream, inputstreamreader

I have a data stream of data aquisition info coming in like a burst pipe. (Actually 3 of them).

I can read and println the data to the console, and never miss any data.

I am now saving the data to a database and this is of course a bottleneck. I have this running at an impressive speed also.

The backlog is causing the socket to stop receiving data and the sender stops sending data. The program continues to work through the buffer for some time.

Is there a way to get the buffer size for this stream? I would like to clear the buffer after having read enough data.

I'm not sure if this would be in the socket, the socket, the InputStream or the InputStreamReader.

```java
InputStream inputStream1 = socket1.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader1 = new InputStreamReader(inputStream1, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

if (inputStreamReader.ready()) {
    recMsg(inputStreamReader, inputStream, (LinkedList) msgFifo);  // Get more data
    //System.out.print("Got More data: ");
}
```

```java
public static void recMsg(InputStreamReader inputStreamReader, InputStream inputStream,LinkedList msgFifo) throws IOException {
    int x;
    int loop = 0;
    boolean ready;
    while ((x = inputStreamReader.read()) != -1) {
        char result = (char)x;
        msgFifo.add(x);
        loop += 1;
        ready = inputStreamReader.ready();

        if (loop >= bufferSize * 2) break; //bufferSize is 2048
        if(!ready) break;
    }
```

I'm working on learning Java and I know some of the code is not great.

Comment: The use of the `.ready()` method, especially by a beginner, is usually a sign that a much better design is possible. However, all the choices here, from the LinkedList to store input, to the use of Reader to read single characters at a time from the socket seem to be clumsy and inefficient. Perhaps a little bit of a description of what you're trying to do would result in some ideas for improvement.

Comment: I am receiving data from 3 data acquisition module using Ethernet cable to a switch to the PC.
The data arrives in large blocks every second or so. The data is coded with a starting bit and is bytes of data that are swapped and two 7 bit number become a 14 bit analog number.
I save the data into Fifos for later saving. 
I then parse the data time stamp it and save to 3 databases one for each module. I am using Sqlite3. 
I save the data by turing off the Autocommit and doing a commit at the end of a block. Much faster.
The later data use is not my problem.

Comment: I read that using the inputStreamReader.ready() is not good practice but i could not get it to work using other methods. It always ended up hanging  if the buffer was empty. The x = inputStreamReader.read())!=-1 will not work if there is nothing there to read.

Comment: My big problem is that the data is coming in faster than I can save it. It's also messing with the timestamp i put on it. How can I clear the buffer?

Comment: Am I doing something wrong here? Am I asking a question in a way that upsets people? So far I have only received a "your too dumb to be on here" reply.